# Is there any way to increment a number each time the file gets executed in ruby

Tags: ruby, code-coverage

Is there any way to increment a no. each time the file gets executed in ruby.
I didn't find anything in this matter.
I want to declare a no. and then it will be incremented each time the file in which it resides gets executed.
I can use file to keep track of last no. used but is there any simple solution

Comment: Where do you want to keep that number?

Comment: No, I think you have to use Database or File as you have done

Comment: @Bohdan I don't want to keep track of it that function will,I will just ask the function what is next no.

Comment: @Salil thanks but I think there should be a function for this,but if there isn't then I have to do the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# 0 TIMES
def  get_no
  me = File.read(__FILE__)
  me.sub!(/ \d+ TIMES/) { |s| " #{s[/\d+/].to_i + 1} TIMES" }
  l=me.split("\n")
  File.open(__FILE__,'w') { |f| f.write(me) }
  return l[0][/\d+/]
end
```

This method will give me next no each time I call it and also will keep track of it thanks to Alex D

Answer (score 2):

If you are `load`ing the file repeatedly from inside a long-running Ruby process, then that's pretty easy:

```
$times_loaded ||= 0
$times_loaded += 1
```

If you are running the file in a new Ruby interpreter process each time, then you'll have to use a file (it couldn't work any other way). You could make the Ruby file self-modifying:

```
# THIS FILE HAS RUN 0 TIMES
me = File.read(__FILE__)
me.sub!(/THIS FILE HAS RUN \d+ TIMES/) { |s| "THIS FILE HAS RUN #{s[/\d+/].to_i + 1} TIMES" }
File.open(__FILE__,'w') { |f| f.write(me) }
```

Comment: By the way, I haven't tested this code yet... it is just to give you the idea.

Comment: Please note that this is a pretty crazy thing to do! But you can do it if you really want to.

Comment: Glad to hear it! If this solved your problem, an accept and +1 would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use ruby's [coverage capability](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/coverage/rdoc/Coverage.html) or a code coverage tool like [SimpleCov](http://www.rubyinside.com/simplecov-a-powerful-straightforward-ruby-1-9-code-coverage-tool-3712.html)?